# openssl hmac differ from python hmac

Tags: python, openssl, hmac

with:

```
KEY='7vgd39eyxald9sucClM7'
DATA='POST\nmultipart/form-data\nWed, 10 Jun 2015 07:27:43 GMT\n/1/classes/item\nx-wbs-uid:f886a495220975d724ff3679a5cc9cef04343076'
```

in command line

```
HASH_BIN=`echo -n "$DATA" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt key:$KEY -binary`
openssl enc -e -base64 <<< $HASH_BIN
result: VmBdzRcNg0OJZVVLSgg1zcViflug9iqtb6Gsnjqf9F8K
```

in python

```
import hmac, hashlib, base64
hash = hmac.new(KEY, DATA, hashlib.sha256).digest()
base64.encodestring(hash).strip()
result: u6Poj7Jqrz6+wvXDNyK88pVm5iKUF6RUmq2P2LtHmuE=
```

Can someone give me a help??? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you  paste the entire Python code including KEY and DATA definition?

Comment: Good question. I did the experiments and found the same problem as you. When I tried to use a different and simpler DATA string ( without '\n'), the openssl and python can produce the same result. So I found the problem is caused by the string definition in python.

Answer (score 6):

It should be caused by the `DATA` string definition in your python code.

You need add `r` to treat the `DATA` as a raw string, such as

```
DATA=r'POST\nmultipart/form-data\nWed, 10 Jun 2015 07:27:43 GMT\n/1/classes...'
```

With the `r`, all escape codes in `DATA` will be ignored. That is to say, '\n' will be treated as a newline character, but r'\n' will be treated as the characters \ followed by n. In Python,

```
'\n'  // 0x0d

r'\n' // 0x5c 0x6e
```

With the `r`, it will output the result equals to output via openssl,

```
VmBdzRcNg0OJZVVLSgg1zcViflug9iqtb6Gsnjqf9F8K
```